# Select values from a range to the right of a given cell and iteratively create a subfolder from them

Tags: vba, excel, filesystems

Hope you are well.

I'm trying to create a mass folder creator using Excel and vba. It's my first time using VBA as I usually focus on web-based languages so forgive me for my lack of knowledge in advance. I have some code already it's just putting the finishing touches that I'm struggling with.

Currently, the user specifies a directory in a given cell and name of the parent file in another cell. Upon clicking a button, the macro creates the parent folder using the directory and name from the parent file cell. It then creates sub folders using the values of any cells the respondent has selected upon running the macro.

I am currently struggling with the next stage of the project which is creating sub-folders (I'll just call them Grandchildren) within the subfolders. This would be easy if all of the subfolders had the same Grandchildren however, this is not the case. What I would like to do is grab the 3 values to the right of each cell which defines the name of the subfolder and use them to create the Grandchildren however I'm currently getting the  'Invalid Qualifier' message with the code I am currently using (see below).

```
BasePath = Range("folder_path")

'Check if the project folder already exists and if so raise and error and exit
If Dir(BasePath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
MsgBox BasePath & " already exists", , "Error"
Else

'Create the project folder
MkDir BasePath

MsgBox "Parent folder creation complete"

'Loop through the 1st tier subfolders and create them
For Each c In ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Cells
    'create new folder path
    NewFolder = BasePath & "\" & c.Value
    'create folder

    If fs.folderexists(NewFolder) Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        MkDir NewFolder
    End If

Next c

'Create GrandChildren
For Each d In ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Cells
    'Offset the selection to the right

    For Each e In d.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3).Cells

    Test = e.Value
    GrandChild = BasePath & "\" & d.Value & "\" & Test

    If fs.folderexists(GrandChild) Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        MkDir GrandChild
    End If

Next e
Next d

MsgBox "Sub-folder creation complete"

End If

End Sub
```

If you require any further information please let me know.

Cheers,

Jason

Comment: Exactly which line throws the error?  You should make the change suggested in the answer below - the way you have it in your post is not correct.

Comment: I've edited my original post. It's a compilation error. It highlights Sub create_folders() in yellow and Test in the line below in blue (GrandChild = BasePath & "\" & d.Value & "\" & Test.Value )

Comment: The Test.Value bit does not need .Value on the end. My final query is how to make Test a range of 3 cells rather than just the 1.

Comment: Create a loop inside your "for each d" loop `For Each c in d.Offset(0,1).Resize(1,3).Cells`  Then Test = c.Value, rest of code is the same.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Tim, it works perfectly. I've ammended the original code for anyone else who wants to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is here

`Test = d.Offset(0, 1).Select`

Test is a String and you are selecting a cell.  You should try this:

```
Test = d.Offset(0,1).Value
```

Comment: I've solved the 'Invalid Qualifier' problem. Test.Value is invalid. All you need is Test. I've edited my original post. My final query is how to make Test a range of 3 cells rather than just the 1.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful, it's a simple routine I use to make ALL the folders in an entire path fed into the function.

EXAMPLE:

1. C:\2011\Test\
2. C:\2012\Test
3. C:\2013\Test\DeepTest\
4. C:\2014\Test\DeeperTest\DeeperStill

Based on the list above, this macro will attempt to create 11 directories, ones that exist already...no problem.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeDirectories()
'Author:    Jerry Beaucaire, 7/11/2010
'Summary:   Create directories and subdirectories based
'           on the text strings listed in column A
'           Parses parent directories too, no need to list separately
'           10/19/2010 - International compliant
Dim Paths   As Range
Dim Path    As Range
Dim MyArr   As Variant
Dim pNum    As Long
Dim pBuf    As String
Dim Delim   As String

Set Paths = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
Delim = Application.PathSeparator
On Error Resume Next

    For Each Path In Paths
        MyArr = Split(Path, Delim)
        pBuf = MyArr(LBound(MyArr)) & Delim
        For pNum = LBound(MyArr) + 1 To UBound(MyArr)
            pBuf = pBuf & MyArr(pNum) & Delim
            MkDir pBuf
        Next pNum
        pBuf = ""
    Next Path

Set Paths = Nothing

End Sub
```

There is a UDF version too and a sample file for testing [found here](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/text-functions/make-folders).   FYI.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for the solution above. Unfortunately the macro I am developing in Excel needs to be accessible to users with poor computer literacy (therefore menu driven and as simple as possible). From what I understand of your code above, users would have to enter the full path of each folder which (as we are using network drives) most of the users in my company would not know. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Oh heavens no, the UDF is the final tool you would use in this case. That is designed to accept strings you assemble any way you wish.  You could have a main string in your calling macro and then take folder information from cells, constructing the string, so to speak, however you wish, then feed that to the UDF which will literally make ever folder necessary from that point.